# HashMap in Solana Rust Contract

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, sol

My HashMap is not functioning properly on Solana when using a Rust program. Is there an alternative approach to achieving a similar functionality to a HashMap? Essentially, I want to retrieve data associated with each user who has donated SOL. When I paste an address, I want to find out what they have donated.

Answer (score 3):

For your application, the "Solana" way would be to create a PDA for each user who has donated when the donation ix runs, e.g:

```
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"user-data-acc", user.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = payer,
        space = SIZE_OF_YOUR_STRUCT
    )]
    pub user_data: Account<'info, YourUserDataAcc>,
```

Now you can store whatever information you want in that struct, like:

```
#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct YourUserDataAcc {
    pub some_key: Pubkey,
    pub another_key: Pubkey,
    pub amt: u64,
}
```

And now you can always derive and load your struct for some userKey the front end with:

```
PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("user-data-acc", "utf-8"), userKey.toBuffer()],
    programId
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Hashmaps aren't supported in Solana. Try using a Btree instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion, can you please recommend some docs or code for Btree?

Comment: check out this gist https://gist.github.com/FrankC01/abae44f481c67988820fbb8c2c836c27.

What are you using the hashmap for?